# How to integrate shiny, leaflet and ncWMS?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, wms

I have setup a ncWMS server which serve my netcdf file into web map server. Now I would like to integrate ncWMS serve with my shiny APP through R leaflet package:

There is no problem to show the example code, but always get the empty leaflet results.

My codes are :

library(leaflet)

```
leaflet() %>% 
    addTiles() %>% 
    setView(133, -23, zoom = 4) %>%
    addWMSTiles(
        "https://croptsrv-cdc.it.csiro.au/ncWMS/wms",
        layers = "fi/mint",
        options = WMSTileOptions(
                  format = "image/png", 
                  transparent = FALSE, version = "1.3.0",
                                 CRS = 'CRS:84',
                                 styles = 'boxfill/redblue'),
        attribution = ""
    )
```

This is the link for capabilities of ncWMS dataset:

https://croptsrv-cdc.it.csiro.au/ncWMS/wms?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.3.0&DATASET=fi

I have played with URL and options, but still no maps.

How should I show my ncWMS map using leaflet? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't specify CRS in the WMSTileOptions - this works for me:

```
leaflet() %>%
 addTiles() %>%
 setView(133, -23, zoom = 4) %>% 
 addWMSTiles("https://croptsrv-cdc.it.csiro.au/ncWMS/wms",
   layers = "fi/mint",
   options = WMSTileOptions(
     format = "image/png",
     transparent=TRUE,
     styles="boxfill/redblue"))
```

[image: R leaflet WMS]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Could you let me know your session infor? I cannot reproduce the results.

Comment: I think I find the problem. The ncWMS layer ONLY is not working for internal viewer in RStudio desktop version.